# install gulp plugin without NPM install

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, gulp, manifest

I'm building an Android application using Cordova. I want to hot push some code using Cordova App Loader. For creating the manifest I found this Gulp task here:

https://github.com/AlexanderBeyn/gulp-cordova-app-loader-manifest

which I seriously would love to use. Unfortunately, I have no idea of how to get it installed since installing it via NPM doesn't seem to work.

Any one here knows how to get this working on my gulpfile?

thanks so much for your help!

Comment: What about using npm doesn't work? What's the error that you're given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download that from github, put the folder in your node_modules folder in your project.

Just don't forget to do `npm install` in the gulp-cordova-app-loader-manifest folder to download his dependencies.

Now you can do `require('gulp-cordova-app-loader-manifest')` from you gulpfile.

Comment: nice! Thanks for your help!